# NewNativeModule Allocation failed - process out of memory -- on truffle compile

Tags: solidity, truffle

I'm attempting to compile a super basic contract with truffle. It is just the classic Box.sol given in the Openzeppelin docs. However upon compilation, i'm receiving the following error:

[image]

I'm running this directly on my local machine and can't for the life of me figure out what is causing this issue.

Any tips?

Comment: Seems a problem with node. What node version are you using? What's the truffle version? What's the solidity version? If node is too new/old try the latest LTS, if truffle is too old try the latest, if solidity version is old try the most recent one.

Comment: The solidity compilation happens off-chain with truffle, so this looks to be an issue with your actual hardware memory. please check if you have any processes that are eating your memory. Otherwise post your code and your truffle configuration file.